# python logging changing format of the main logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a client-agent structure in Python.

AgentClientLogger.py (contains Logger definition)

```
import logging

def initLogging(loggername,logdir,logfile,loglevel,CMDID,logToConsole=False):
  logger=logging.getLogger(loggername)
  format=logging.Formatter(LOGGER_FORMAT)
  **filehandle definition**
```

Agent.py/Client.py

```
import AgentClientLogger.py

def initLogging():
  global logger
  logger=AgentClientLogger(loggername,logdir,loglevel,CMDID,logToConsole=False)

#MAIN
initLogging()
Actions.init(logger)
```

Actions.py

```
def init(plogger):
  global logger
  logger=plogger

def someFns():
  *do something*
```

So here is the problem i am facing. Keeping this structure and without changing the logger calls too much, how can I change the format of the logger.  So to simplify, I want to use a different format of the logger for the client, a different one for the agent and a different one for the actions. But I want to make all the changes in AgentClientLogging.py so that there is a global common place for all logging settings.

I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work.

Define a class CustomeSettings in AgentClientLogger.py

```
class CustomeSettings(logging):
  *get Handlers*
  * use setFormatter to change format *
```

Can anyone let me know if this is the correct approach. Or what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: I hope I understood, so why not change the `LOGGER_FORMAT`, just put as an argument at `initLogging()` and for each call of `initLogging()` you can deliver a different format, each call should be with a different `loggername`.

Comment: Well the AgentClientLogger.py script has been used as a generic setup script for many parts of my application. I cannot change it without having to undergo a lot of code structure changes.
That is why I was wondering if defining a class to do this dirty work would be a good way

Comment: It's hard to give advice without the rest of the code but did you consider overload `initLogging()` with a new method so the change can be minimal?

Comment: Yeah I did try that. Its a good idea to implement but the code was a bit messy. thanks anyways :)

Comment: I see, i think the overloading will be the best option since it will change only the needed part, One more thing you can check (i don't know if it's possible) is to declare your logger and to create a method just for changing the `Fommater`.